# How to loop through rows of the Excel sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, selenium, loops, rows

I am using Python, Selenium, openpyxl in order to fill a form online. 
To fill the form I am taking values from specific cells on excel (.xlsx). 
(to test the code you can just create and excel file with 2 columns, insert under column A some names and column B some age.

- From the cell `A2`, I take the NAME of the person and insert it into the online form
- From the cell `B2`, I take the LASTNAME of the person and insert it into the online form
- Then I click 'Reset' (This is an example but in the real code I will click save as a draft).

I would like to create a loop in which the code will start again from `driver.get("https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields")` to go again to the page where I need to fill out the form, but this time I would like to take:

- From the cell `A3`, the NAME of the person and insert it into the online form
- From the cell `B3`, the LASTNAME of the person and insert it into the online form
- And click 'Send as a draft' again

Then again, another loop to insert the data from row 4, so I would like to program to read again my code from `driver.get("https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields")` but this time take values from `A4` and `B4`, and so on, until the row on excel is empty.

With the following code I can insert the data to the online form:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import openpyxl

driver: WebDriver = 
webdriver.Chrome("/Users/HHHHH/PycharmProjects/excel/driver/chromedriver")

driver.maximize_window()

excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"/Users/XPATH OF THE EXCEL FILE YOU CREATE TO TEST THIS CODE", 
data_only=True)

sheet = excel_document["Sheet1"]



driver.get("https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields")

#Insert in the form the Name of the person

prevsymbol = sheet["A2"].value
if prevsymbol == None:
    pass
else:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_name("02frstname").send_keys(sheet["A2"].value)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("A2:(name) Not Found")

#Insert in the form the Last Name of the person

prevsymbol = sheet["B2"].value
if prevsymbol == None:
    pass
else:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_name("04lastname").send_keys(sheet["B2"].value)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("B2:(Lastname) Not Found")

#click Save as a draft

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@value='Reset']").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of rows in the sheet using the `max_row` property. So, the code becomes:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import openpyxl

driver: WebDriver = 
webdriver.Chrome("/Users/HHHHH/PycharmProjects/excel/driver/chromedriver")

driver.maximize_window()

excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"/Users/HHHHH/Desktop/testtesttest1.xlsx", 
data_only=True)

sheet = excel_document["Sheet1"]

for i in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    driver.get("https://XXXXXXXXXX")    
    # Insert in the form the Name of the person
    cell = "A" + str(i)
    prevsymbol = sheet[cell].value
    # Note that instead of doing the work at the else clause, you can negate the term
    if prevsymbol is not None:
        try:
            # Note that we can use prevsymbol here, instead of referring to cell once again
            driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(prevsymbol)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            #
            print(cell + ":(name) Not Found")

    # Insert in the form the Age of the person  
    cell = "B" + str(i)
    prevsymbol = sheet[cell].value
    if prevsymbol is not None:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id("age").send_keys(prevsymbol)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print(cell + ":(Age) Not Found")

    # Click Save as a draft    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_save_as_draft").click()
```

Comment: prevsymbol = sheet["A" + str(i)].value
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

To make it easy, if you create an excel file with two columns and insert in one random names and in the other random age, then you follow this code (changing the path of the driver and the path of where the code finds the excel file you have created on your computer) and adding those details:
driver.get("https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields")
driver.find_element_by_name("02frstname").send_keys(prevsymbol)
driver.find_element_by_name("04lastname").send_keys(prevsymbol)

Comment: @Alessio I figured out the problem. The range was specified incorrectly (Python range starts from 0 whereas Excel ranges start from 1). I am updating my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have create a helper class please find if it fulfill your purpose. This code is done in old version of openpyxl. Please update code if needed.

```
class OpenpyxlImport(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        if self.file.name.endswith('.xls'):
            self.wb = self.xls_to_xlsx(self.file)
        else:
            self.wb = load_workbook(self.file)
        self.sheets = self.wb.worksheets

    def to_camelcase(self, string):
        text = re.sub(r'(?!^)_([a-zA-Z])', lambda m: ' ' + m.group(1).upper(), str(string))
        return text.upper()

    def to_snake_case(self, string):
        text = re.sub(r'\s', '_', str(string))
        return text.lower()

    def xls_to_xlsx(self, content):
        xls_book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=content.read())
        workbook = openpyxlWorkbook()

        for i in range(0, xls_book.nsheets):
            xls_sheet = xls_book.sheet_by_index(i)
            sheet = workbook.active if i == 0 else workbook.create_sheet()
            sheet.title = xls_sheet.name

            for row in range(0, xls_sheet.nrows):
                for col in range(0, xls_sheet.ncols):
                    sheet.cell(row=row + 1, column=col + 1).value = xls_sheet.cell_value(row, col)
        return workbook

    def tally_header(self, row, fields):
        # Strip whitespace in cell value
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = cell.value.rstrip()
        return [cell.value for cell in row] == fields

    def row_to_dict(self, row):
        dct = {}
        for cell in row:
            dct[self.to_snake_case(self.get_first_sheet()[cell.column + '1'].value)] = cell.value
        return dct

    def get_sheets(self):
        return self.sheets

    def get_first_sheet(self):
        return self.sheets[0]

    def get_sheet_rows(self):
        return tuple(self.get_first_sheet().iter_rows())

# Usage
excel = OpenpyxlImport(file)
rows = excel.get_sheet_rows()
if excel.tally_header(rows[0], self.fields):
    for row in rows[1:]:
        params = excel.row_to_dict(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Roshan, but Im a beginner n cannot adapt your example to mine. To make it easy, if u create an excel file with 2 columns and insert in one random names and in the other random age, then you follow this code (changing the path of the driver and the path of where the code finds the excel file you have created on your computer) and adding those details: driver.get("roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields") driver.find_element_by_name("02frstname").send_keys(prevsymbol) driver.find_element_by_name("04lastname").send_keys(prevsymbol) driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@value='Reset']").click()

Comment: What I would like to do is that once the program wrote in the correct online form the data from A2 and B2 and I clicked "Save as a draft", the program could re-read the same code from driver.get("XXXXXXXXXX") and starts reading the code again but instead of filling values from A2 and B2 from excel, could fill in values A3 and B3, then loop again to insert value A4 in one window of the online form and B4 in the other window and so on until finds a completely empty row.

Comment: Here, after reading you can get latest row by checking length of row to go to latest row, `row_to_dict` gives you value of that row. Going to last row using index + 1 gives empty row to fill then `for i, value in enumerate(args):
            cell = self.ws.cell(row=self.row_idx, column=i + 1)
            cell.value = value` where `args is ['<name>', '<last_name>']`

Comment: Ok, but once the code inserts the data from the first row, how can I tell the program to pass to the second row and do the same process? Is there a way to use a "Repeat" function telling the code from which point the code needs to be repeated and to change A2 in A3 and B2 in B3? I have tried with itinerate funciton but it insert all rows of column A and All rows of column B at the same time, while I would like the program to write A2, then click on the next online window and insert B2, then click save as draft and then add to a new form data from A3 in a window and B3 in the next window etc...